# Tuning out from world sound design

Tags: design, film, sound, movies

Hi can you recommend movies where the main characters get overwhelmed and they start to "tune out" from the real world and their surroundings? (The effect being that everything is slowly brought down in terms of level, or sometimes replaced by just a ringing in the ear. Usually accompanied by slow motion picture, etc.)

I know this happens a lot in war movies but I forget which titles. Also, if there are non-war movies that use this style.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highly relevant, you will enjoy digesting the many examples in here: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShellShockSilence

Mass Effect games also have this effect when you're "low health", a low-pass filter blurs the music until you recover:

Answer (score 2):

The beach scene in Saving Private Ryan. Check it out at 4:35.